# The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.10 Release' is not signed

Tags: apt, 18.10

I got an error when trying to update ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The response below

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://mirrors.bangmod.cloud/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.10  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1488EB46E192A257
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.10  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```